# How to configure routing in Codeigniter for Rest server?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I use the following library "Codeigniter Rest Server":
https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

I have a standart controller:

```
class Messages extends REST_Controller
{
    public function dialogs(){
        echo "Test"; 
    }
}
```

I try to call this method from URL:

```
http://localhost/api/index.php/messages/dialogs
```

Where `messages` - controller and `dialogs` - method

I get error:

```
{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"}
```

Comment: You didn't follow it well. Method should be something like `dialogs_get()` or `dialog_post()` for example. Take a look of [this tutorial here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter does some simplification for you: the location of the controller "Messages" with the method "dialogs" is automatically given an address of: 
`http://localhost/api/messages/dialogs`. It seems that the REST_Controller has a "_remap" method to redirect your `dialogs()` function back up into the default CodeIgniter path

This could change depending on where the "application" folder is placed, I'm assuming it's inside the folder `api` on your localhost

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Tpojka in the comment, you need to specify the method in the method.

Eg:

```
class Messages extends REST_Controller
{
    public function dialogs_get(){
        echo "Test"; 
    }
}
```

You can call this API in POSTMAN using the method 'GET' and URL endpoint will be

```
http://localhost/api/messages/dialogs
```